# Чем отличаются переменные в jQuery c $ и без

Tags: jquery

Чем отличаются переменные вида:

```
var this_obj=$("div");
и
var $this_obj=$("div");
```

Больше интересует применение таких переменных, в каких случаях и почему?

Comment: синтаксически - ни чем, но лексически вы показываете, что эта переменная  - это jQuery Object, со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

Comment: Сам javascript не исключает обозначение переменных со знаком $!

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на вопрос «[Что означает доллар?](http://hashcode.ru/questions/84909/)»

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ничем не отличаются, лично я использую переменные с префиксом '$', когда она содержит объект jQuery, чтобы было легче читать код.

Comment: Тогда будет ли правилен код:

    $($this_obj).append(...);

?
знаю что так правильно:

    $(this_obj).append(...);
    this_obj.append(...);

Comment: первая запись избыточна, достаточно

    $this_obj.append(...);

если объект уже находится в DOM, то изменения будут выдны в html, но лучше изначально сделать все необходимые монипуляции с `$this_obj`, а уже потом вставлять его в DOM

Answer (score 1):

Недавно был такой вопрос, ничем они не отличаются, это просто общая рекоммендация, можно так писать, если хотите показать, что это объект jquery